# Удаление пустоты

Tags: c++

Я новичок в c++ и сегодня столкнулся с проблемой, которая связана с обработкой строк. Для более понятного объяснения приведу пример:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    cout << str.length() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Если в консоли передать к примеру строку "символы", то `str.length()` вернёт значение 14. Но если сначала написать любую последовательность **русских** символов и потом стереть её , то значение `str.length()` станет больше на количество стёртых символов, например сначала напишем "см", после чего сотрём и вновь напишем "символы", тогда значение `str.length()` станет равно 16. Но поводом для действительно долгих размышлений, стало то, что если стереть "см" и ещё 2 раза стереть пустоту и ввести "символы", тогда `str.length()` вновь возвращает 14. Почему или из-за чего так происходит?

Comment: Так вы посмотрите, какие коды у символов там. Подозреваю, что там записывается [backspace](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backspace). Он в UTF-8 как раз по одному байту занимает.

Comment: Но почему тогда в конечном итоге `str.length()`, возвращает 14? Возможно я вас неправильно понял, но тогда с увеличением количества backspace, длина должна расти, а она всё же стала первоначальной.

Comment: Русские символы в UTF-8 занимают 2 байта, а ваш backspace, похоже, почему-то стирает по одному байту (то есть по пол-символа), это вроде всё объясняет

Comment: @andreymal Получается даже после того, как в консоли отображается пустое пространство, эти "полусимволы" продолжают существовать?

Comment: это не нормальная ситуация... какая ОС и что используешь в качестве терминала?

Comment: @Fat-Zer macOS, Xcode

Comment: @shalor1k, по этому поводу ничего вразумительного сказать не смогу... я бы грешил или на некорректную настойку локали или на баг в xcode... ради интереса можешь попробовать, воспроизводится ли это в нормальном терминале...

Comment: под linux терминалами не смог воспроизвести. Видимо, это просто бажина мак-терминала. Я бы попробовал воспользоваться iTerm или подобными и проверить там.

Comment: @Fat-Zer Я проверил в паре онлайн компиляторах и терминале, точно такая же проблема

Comment: то что онлайн компиляторы кладут болт на корректную работу с локалью и с другими тонкими вещами удивления не вызывает, но проблема в данном случае именно на стороне терминала, а не компилятора или программы... как нормально должна быть настроена локаль в macos и где погладить её терминалы я сказать не смогу... как вариант можешь посмотреть [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606570/os-x-terminal-utf-8-issues)...

Comment: Кроме длины, выводите в своих экспериментах еще и символы строки и смотрите их (лучше чем-то вроде xd  или od)

Comment: @avp Спасибо за ваш комментарий, обязательно попробую